# Luxury Vinyl Flooring Crack

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, vinyl-flooring

I just noticed this crack on our luxury vinyl floors. The top part of the crack has overlapped the bottom piece and it can not be pushed down to create a flat surface.

The only thing I can find online consistent with this crack is if you drop something on the floor such as heavy furniture, but we didn't. I have absolutely no idea how this inch crack happened on our floor. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: From your description that is a manufacturing defect.

Comment: That doesn't look like someone dropped something to me.  It looks to me like there's something under the plank, where the plank got stepped on and the "something" caused the broken part to break upward.

Comment: I think i have to agree Huesmann. This crack was not here when the floors were put in almost a year and a half ago. It randomly appeared a day or two ago. This hallway does have high traffic so maybe something below finally popped through or something is settling beneath it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As to fixing it, that is gonna be a bear.  The only way to fix with zero notion that the "crack" is there would be to replace that panel, which would ordinarily involve removing and replacing a bunch of panels.  Another option—but not an invisible one—could be to peel the cracked part off, excavate enough material below it to allow it to lay flat, and glue it back in.  The level of invisibility would depend on how clean a job you did.